# Youtube iphone integration

Tags: ios, youtube

I'm working on an app that has a video tab, i want to show some video from youtube an was wondering what is the best way of doing it. I've seen some app that seem to have embedded the youtube mobile site can we do that via the UIWeb or what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a UIWebView.  [Here's](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application) a little tutorial that should get you going.